# Gitlab CI how to re-use conditions in variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

In my gitlab-ci.yml I want to re-use conditions using variables.

So instead of this:

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "job executed"
  rules:
    -  if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG =~ "example" || $MY_VAR == "value" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG =~ "test"

job2:
  variables:
    MY_VAR: value
  script:
    - echo "job executed"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG =~ "example" || $MY_VAR == "value"
```

I can do this:

```
variables:
  EXAMPLE_CONDITION: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG =~ "example" || $MY_VAR == "value"

job1:
  script:
    - echo "job executed"
  rules:
    - if: $EXAMPLE_CONDITION && $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG =~ "test"

job2:
  variables:
    MY_VAR: value
  script:
    - echo "job executed"
  rules:
    - if: $EXAMPLE_CONDITION
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work and the rules do not apply as expected.

Is there a way to put `rules:if` conditions into variables?

Comment: This seems like a use case for [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts)